# Relevant data for cost attribute to calculate route time

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, time, route

I have imported OSM data into PgRouting database.
I would like to use driving_distance() function to calculate route time.

How to add relevant time cost into database ?

Answer (score 2):

Time depends on how you travel in your network. Do you walk, do you use bicycle or car or something else?

You can use anything as `cost`, any value or formula. For example you have road classes in your OSM data and you can estimate the average speed on each road class. Then together with the length of the road segment you can calculate the time it takes to pass this road segment.